# R - Loop through directory throws error but I do not know where (try and catch)

Tags: r, loops, try-catch

I have a loop, which is supposed to take all files which fit the provided Regex.
However, some files obviously don't have the correct amount of columns in all rows. Therefore, the loop crashes.
I do now want to find out, which files cause these errors. There are 100s of files, but only a few that do cause this error.
I know from Java, that I would now try to make a try-catch clause and to print the name of the files in order to find them, have a look and erase/change them. I can't deal with that in R though:

```
#PATH WITH ALL FILES
files <- list.files(path="/Users/Test/Trackingpoint", 
pattern="Trackingpoint.*\\.csv\\.gz", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

Trackingpoint_Tables <- 
  tryCatch({
    lapply(files, function(x) {
      a <- read.table(gzfile(x), sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
    })
  }, warning = function(w) {
    print(w)
  }, error = function(e) {
    print(e)  
    })
```

As you know, what I have in w and e is not the file itself, but the error. How can I print the file's name and respectively any other information from the file itself?
I want my code to ignore the errors and just proceed, but to tell me, where this error occures (which file).
Right now, it only says:

```
<simpleError in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,     nmax = nrows, skip = 0, na.strings = na.strings, quiet = TRUE,     fill = fill, strip.white = strip.white, blank.lines.skip = blank.lines.skip,     multi.line = FALSE, comment.char = comment.char, allowEscapes = allowEscapes,     flush = flush, encoding = encoding, skipNul = skipNul): line 24610 did not have 44 elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple change from `read.table` to `read.csv` and `fill=TRUE` were sufficient.